# How to upload video directly from client browser to Viemeo using jquery?

Tags: api, vimeo, video-upload

I have try to upload a video to vimeo account directly from browser using api ,video details are created but file seems to corrupted/upload not happens.This is my sample code.

```
   var file = $(this).prop("files")[0];
       var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file_data", file);
    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/",
                    type: "post",
                    data: formData,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer -----", 
                    },
                    processData: false,
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                  
                }).done(function (response) {
                    
                               // Do something
                         
                       
                    }).complete(function (response) {
                       // Do something
               
                    }).fail(function (e) {
                    // Do something
                });
```

vimeo video listing shows blank thumbnail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nx4s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code. I have made some changes here:

```javascript
var file = $(this).prop("files")[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file_data", file);

$.ajax("https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/", {
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer -----", 
    },
    data: formData,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",     // changed this
    dataType: "json",

    crossDomain: true            // for CORS policy error
}).done((response) => {
    
    // Do something

}).fail((error) => {
    
    // Do something

}).complete(() => {

    // Do something

});
```

I have chaged `contentType` and removed `mimeType`. I've also removed un-necessary `processData` field.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but now 'CORS policy' error happens

Comment: Updated my answer. For CORS policy, you have to add a field `crossDomain`. Here is detailed answer about this error https://stackoverflow.com/q/26987727/7109362

Comment: Thank God if I have been able to help you out!